Where is the best place to pitch ideas for cryptographic functions
I am starting from the assumption that lots of people have ideas about a great new cryptographic function, but those are ideas are normally bad because good cryptography is hard, there are lots of pitfalls, etc. "Anyone can create an algorithm that he himself cannot break" - Bruce Schneier. I know there is loads of research out there, but it is hard for an amateur to get a full grasp of it all.
So with that as the context, where is a good place to talk about ideas and get them shot down quickly, but respectfully. In other words, I have an idea, it is probably rubbish because of something that I don't know about, but I would like to know either way.
Thanks.
